# Best way to implement background “timer” functionality in Python/Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, scheduled-tasks, python-multithreading

I am trying to implement a Django web application (on Python 3.8.5) which allows a user to create “activities” where they define an activity duration and then set the activity status to “In progress”.
The POST action to the View writes the new status, the duration and the start time (end time, based on start time and duration is also possible to add here of course).
The back-end should then keep track of the duration and automatically change the status to “Finished”.
User actions can also change the status to “Finished” before the calculated end time (i.e. the timer no longer needs to be tracked).

I am fairly new to Python so I need some advice on the smartest way to implement such a concept?

It needs to be efficient and scalable – I’m currently using a Heroku Free account so have limited system resources, but efficiency would also be important for future production implementations of course.

I have looked at the Python threading Timer, and this seems to work on a basic level, but I’ve not been able to determine what kind of constraints this places on the system – e.g. whether the spawned Timer thread might prevent the main thread from finishing and releasing resources (i.e. Heroku Dyno threads), etc.
I have read that persistence might be a problem (if the server goes down), and I haven’t found a way to cancel the timer from another process (the .cancel() method seems to rely on having the original object to cancel, and I’m not sure if this is achievable from another process).

I was also wondering about a more “background” approach, i.e. a single process which is constantly checking the database looking for activity records which have reached their end time and swapping the status.
But what would be the best way of implementing such a server?
Is it practical to read the database every second to find records with an end time of “now”?  I need the status to change in real-time when the end time is reached.
Is something like Celery a good option, or is it overkill for a single process like this?

As I said I’m fairly new to these technologies, so I may be missing other obvious solutions – please feel free to enlighten me!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of resolution would you be working to? Would their duration go into seconds? (*For example: Duration 12:10 or 12:10:55*)

Comment: Yes, accuracy to the exact second would be necessary, potentially with multiple activities ending in the same second.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need some kind of **scheduling tasks** functionality. For a fast simpler implementation is a good solution to use the **Timer** object from the
[Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module.

A more complete solution is tu use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/index.html). If you are new, deeping in it will give you a good value start using celery as a queue manager distributing your work easily across several threads or process.

You mentioned that you want it to be efficient and scalable, so I guess you will want to implement similar functionalities that will require multiprocessing and schedule so for that reason my recommendation is to use celery.

You can integrate it into your Django application easily following the documentation [Integrate Django with Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've been trying to do some homework regarding Celery and have some additional thoughts regarding this...  I could possibly use "apply_async" with an ETA for each activity (as I understand this is the earliest something can run might not run the task exactly on time according to the documentation).  Or I could create a periodic task which runs every second to check for database entries with an end time matching the current time and update the status of all of them in one process.

Comment: My main concerns are:
- How accurate will the status change time be (including when multiple activities end at the same time)?
- Could server problems result in missed status changes?
- How much system load will be generated by this?
Do you have further advice with respect to these?

Comment: I think that best approach is to queue a scheduled periodic task (every second) that checks activities that are "in_progress" status and changes it to "finished" status.

Comment: The accurate status change time will depend on the scheduled frequency.
I recommend also to isolate celery service from the application service. Celery has great capabilities, can be easily scaled distributing tasks work load across multiple workers.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice.  I had to put this work on hold for a little while, but I will start it up again soon and check out this suggestion.